# How can I Hide the button on (activity history Standard layout)based on the field selected on Accounts

Tags: workflow, account, contact, button, help

I have 3 fields on Account  and 3 different  buttons on contacts

```
On Account If Field A has value then Button 1 should appear to the User
On Account If Field B has Value then Button 2 Should appear to the User
On Account If Field C has value then Button 3 should appear to the User
```

I  tried by workflow rule but its not working

Comment: Are the buttons on the Standard Contact page? On a custom VF page? On the Account's Contact related List? something else?

Comment: Standard Contact Page

Answer (score 1):

For the standard Contact page, you could solve this by

1. Adding recordTypes to Contact where the recordTypeId is set by workflow or Process builder based on the value of Account fields a-b-c.
2. Using different page layouts for the three record types - each with different buttons

Or, you could replace the standard Contact page with a simple VF page that exploited `apex:detail` and some jQuery to hide the irrelevant buttons. This involves essentially hacking the generated HTML on the standard page to use css `display:none` to hide buttons. [There is an SFSE question/answer on this approach here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13529/conditional-rendering-of-buttons-when-using-apexdetail-and-inlineedit-true).

Once the VF page is constructed, override the View button on the `Setup | Customize | Contacts |Buttons and Links` page to use the VF page